# Why does list* in Clojure only work with a vector in tail position?

Tags: clojure

I am a clojure newbie. I am trying to play around `repl` and i see the following as output. And I don't quite understand why each of them behave so differently

```
(def a (list 1 2 3))  =>#'test.core/a

(list* 4 5 a)          =>(4 5 1 2 3)

(list* a 4 5)         =>IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:542)
```

why does the above 2 statements behave the same way in the above 2 statements?

```
(list* 4 5 [1 2 3])     =>(4 5 1 2 3)

(list* 4 5 [a])       =>(4 5 (1 2 3))

(list* 4 5 (1 2))     =>ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  test.core/eval3837 (form-init633779145118520639.clj:1)
```

Could someone explain why each of the above statement has a different output?

Comment: Insofar as our goal is to build a knowledgebase, every question should have a distinct and useful title. If we had thousands of questions titled "Explain the output of this program in [languge-X]", nobody could ever find something useful in the knowledge base (since they'd need to open every single question and look at what "this code" was, to see if it matched what they had a problem with).

Comment: Have you tried evaluating `(1 2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the doc string for list*:

> Creates a new seq containing the items prepended to the rest, the last
>   of which will be treated as a sequence.

Note a seq is not a list but lists and vectors and other things can be treated as sequences. Also a seq when output at the repl looks like a list - it is printed within parens.

So in the first case your last argument is a literal vector and it is treated as a sequence and you get an unnested sequence.

In the second case you have the list 'a' as a single element within a literal vector so the vector is treated as a sequence but the inner list is not, your returned sequence is three elements long: 4, 5, and the list a.

In the last case you are tripping up on the function call syntax in lisps being very similar to the list syntax. (1 2) is trying to call the number 1 as if it in a function (with the argument 2). A literal number can not be interpreted as a function.

If you want a list literal not a function call you have to quote it:

```
(list* 4 5 '(1 2)) => (4 5 1 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [definition](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L640) and docstring, it'll make sense.

The docs say:

> "Creates a new seq containing the items prepended to the rest, **the last of which will be treated as a sequence**."

Emphasis mine.

In the first block, the last expression fails because 5 is the last argument, but  isn't a sequence.

`(list* 4 5 [1 2 3])` works for the same reason that `(list* 4 5 a)` works. The last argument is a sequence, as it's expecting. It just `cons` onto the last argument as you can see in the definition.

`(list* 4 5 [a])` gives different results because you've wrapped the collection `a` in another collection. It just adds onto the outer collection, leaving the inner one untouched.

The failure of `(list* 4 5 (1 2))` isn't really a related problem. Remember, any time you have `(...)` unquoted, it will attempt to evaluate it, and is expecting that the first element in the list is callable. 1 however isn't callable, thus the error. You need to quote it to treat it as a list literal and not code that you want evaluated.

Comment: I agree this improves on my answer for clarity. I appreciate the improvement, although I struggle not to find the tone of your comment somewhat condescending.

Comment: @AlexStoddard Sorry. Honestly, I wrote this answer and comment in a rush because I already had half the answer written, then realized that I was running out of time before I needed to do something else. I added the comment because I figured I would get such a comment from someone anyways. I didn't put a whole lot of thought into the tone. I can write things that sound rude when I'm rushed and highly caffeinated. My apologies.

Comment: Apology most definitely accepted.  I was being too prickly as well. (And your answer is still the better one!). Best regards.